# Not able to identify the web element in gmail login page. Tried by all possible element locators

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package webelements;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class webelements {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\rpremala003\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("#Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
    }
}
```

Please check this code. I tried by executing but it's executing Password and Sign in fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the correct locator for **Password** field.

Replace this line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("#Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
```

With this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
```

In case if any problem while execute above, please do let me know.

Comment: No Mahipal, it didn't work.  Got issue like below   :                     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #Passwd
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '8c03df6', time: '2017-03-02 09:30:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'RPREMALA00387', ip: '10.23.151.33', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'

Comment: I tried all element locators like id, name, tagName, className, xpath and cssSelector but still it's not reading Password and sign in fields. Can someone post the code please

Answer (score 1):

Using `#` in the locator is for `By.cssSelector`. You can use

```
By.id("Passwd")

By.cssSelector("#Passwd")

By.xpath("//*[@id='Passwd']")
```

There is also a delay until the page is loaded. Use explicit wait to wait for the fields

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd")));
password.sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep implicit wait before entering password because as soon as you entered in next page, it take some time to load dom and therefore your webdriver required some time to find element with id = Passwd. Please refer attached lines of code

```
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```

Comment: Krishna, Instead of using `implicit wait`, use `explicit wait`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that your `xpath` is wrong in this line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("#Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
```

Also you are not providing any wait after click on `next` button, at-least wait for few seconds so, that your webdriver will find the element on next page. For more details on this refer my below code.

If you want to access `password web-element` with `xpath locator` then try this below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
```

**Explanation of xpath:**  Use `id` attribute of `<input>` tag.

Try this below code, It will definitely work for you.

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);         //implicit wait

driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();                  

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);      // After click on next button wait for 15 seconds because your page is getting changed. For wait i have used `explicit wait` method.           
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"))));

driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```

Comment: thanks Jainish. When I tried explicit then it worked